# add control to the beginning of other control asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Simple question

can I append control to the beginning of other control

this add to the end of control

```
IdOfControl.control.add(...)
```

I want something Equivalent to jquery .prepend()

```
IdOfControl.control.prepend (...)
```

thanks

Baaroz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create something like this (an extension function)

```
public static class ControlExtensions {
        public static void Prepend(this Control targetCtr, Control newCtr) {
            targetCtr.Parent.Controls.AddAt(targetCtr.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(targetCtr), newCtr);
        }
    }
```

and then I would use it exaclty as you said:

```
ctrl.Prepend(anotherCtrl);
```